# how to cover apex standard set controller variable in test class?

Tags: apex, code-coverage, standardsetcontroller

Apex Class

```
public class Controll{   
 public ApexPages.StandardSetController paged {
         get {
              if(paged == null) {
               paged = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(
               [SELECT Name,age__c from Account]));
             }
             paged.setPageSize(20);
             return paged;
            }
            set;
          }
    public controll(){

    }
 }
```

---

Test Class

```
@isTest
public class Controll_Test {

public static testmethod void ControlTest(){

 Account a=new Account();
 a.name='usdf';
 insert a;
 test.starttest();
 Controll co=new Controll();
  ApexPages.StandardSetController ssc = 
new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator([select name from Account where name='usdf']));
       co.paged=ssc;
       test.stoptest();

}

}
```

Only this line is covered in my test class

> "public ApexPages.StandardSetController paged {"

Answer (score 1):

if you try to access the variable in your test method, the getter will be executed and you will be covering the variable.

```
    @istest
    public class testClass{
      @istest
      static void test(){
           MySampleClass cls = new MySampleClass();
           Sytem.assertNotEqual(cls.paged,null);

  }

}
```